# Creating 1-1 mapping of Array results

Tags: arrays, jsonata

I am trying to use data coming back from an ElasticSearch query, and get it into an Array in jsonata in a certain format.

Essentially, I need my result set to be like this:

```
{
  "userName": [
    "david2@david2.com",
    "david2@david2.com",
    "david2@david2.com",
    "david2@david2.com"
  ],
  "label": [
    "Dealer",
    "Inquiry",
    "DD Test Skill1",
    "_11DavidTest"
  ],
  "value": [
    3,
    5,
    2,
    1
  ]
}
```

However, what I am getting is this:

```
{
  "userName": "david2@david2.com",
  "label": [
    "Dealer",
    "Inquiry",
    "DD Test Skill1",
    "_11DavidTest"
  ],
  "value": [
    3,
    5,
    2,
    1
  ]
}
```

I am using the following to map the results:

```
(
    $data := $map(data.hits.hits._source.item."Prod::User", function($v) {
        {

            "userName": $v.userName,
            "label": $v.userSkillLevels.skill.name,
            "value": $v.userSkillLevels.level
            
            
        }
    });

)
```

And my overall dataset returned form ElasticSearch is as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
      "total": 15,
      "successful": 15,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": {
        "value": 2,
        "relation": "eq"
      },
      "max_score": 1.002851,
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "items_latest_production1_user",
          "_type": "_doc",
          "_id": "63d000766f67d40a73073d5d_f6144acf2b3ff31209ef9f6d461cd849",
          "_score": 1.002851,
          "_source": {
            "item": {
              "Prod::User": {
                "userSkillLevels": [
                  {
                    "level": 3,
                    "skill": {
                      "name": "Dealer"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "skill": {
                      "name": "Inquiry"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "level": 2,
                    "skill": {
                      "name": "DD Test Skill1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "level": 1,
                    "skill": {
                      "name": "_11DavidTest"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "userName": "david2@david2.com"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can see that each user that comes back from Elastic, then as all the skills/levels in an array associated to 1 username.

I need to have the same number of userNames, as their are skills ... and am struggling to get it just right.

Thoughts? Appreciate any help, I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple.

Actually, need this format:

```
[
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "Dealer"
"value" : 3
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "Inquiry"
"value" : 5
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "DD Test Skill"
"value" : 2
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "_11DavidTest"
"value" : 1
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve this is to create the `userName` array yourself and making sure it has the same length as `userSkillLevels.skill`, here's how you can do this:

```
(
    $data := $map(data.hits.hits._source.item."Prod::User", function($v, $i, $a) {
        {

            "userName": $map([1..$count($v.userSkillLevels.skill)], function() {$v.userName}),
            "label": $v.userSkillLevels.skill.name,
            "value": $v.userSkillLevels.level
        }
    });
)
```

Feel free to check out this response in Stedi JSONata Playground: https://stedi.link/PVwGacu

Comment: Thank you, this exactly solved what I asked above, simply.

Now having tried this in my overall code, I need to data slightly different (above didn't give the results I needed, my fault)

I need it in the following:

[
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "Dealer"
"value" : 3
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "Inquiry"
"value" : 5
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "DD Test Skill"
"value" : 2
},
{
"userName" : "david2@david2.com"
"label" : "_11DavidTest"
"value" : 1
}
]


I added this above also, so it is easier to see the format

Comment: @Vacek, here's an adjusted solution for you: https://stedi.link/YnUF3LV

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, need this format:

For the updated format from your question, this solution can produce it using the [parent operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-parent):

```
data.hits.hits._source.item."Prod::User".userSkillLevels.{
  "userName": %.userName,
  "label": skill.name,
  "value": level
}
```

Check it out on the playground: https://stedi.link/gexB3Cb